# I wish I knew in my 20’s vs I wish I had known in my 20’s

Tags: past-perfect, spoken-english, subjunctives, wish

I am a little confused with the usage of **I wish** structure. I understand that when speaking about present we use **I wish + Past** **Simple** while speaking about past we say **I wish + Past Perfect**

So I don’t really understand why so many people write

> Things I wish I **knew** in my 20’s

instead of

> Things I wish I **had known**.

When we are talking about 20’s we are speaking about past, aren’t we? Or is it ok not to use the Past Perfect in headings?

Comment: Native English speakers, who don't give a thought to grammar most of the time, use both structures.  Even well educated speakers make constant mistakes and this is one of them. The past perfect is definitely the correct choice.